# Error Importing aar file in Android Studio 2.2.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Steps taken: New ^ Module ^ Import aar/jar ^ choose file.
I see below exception. Whats wrong ?

> RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.android.tools.idea.gradle.parser.UnparseableStatement cannot be
>   cast to com.android.tools.idea.gradle.parser.Dependency

If I put file in libs and add dependency in build.gradle
`compile (name: 'fileName', ext:'aar')` is works alright.

Can someone tell me what's issue in first approch ?

Answer (score 0):

The IDE isn't tightly coupled with the build-tool. Always add via the build tool (Gradle, in your case) when available.

As for why an error exists. Probably a bug.